# Language detection in Python for big data

Tags: python, nlp, bigdata, language-detection

I am trying to run language detection on a Series object in a pandas dataframe. However, I am dealing with millions of rows of string data, and the standard Python language detection libraries`langdetect` and `langid` are too slow, and after hours of running it still hasn't completed.

I set up my code as follows:

```
#function to detect language
def detect_language (cell):
    if len(cell) > 0:
        lan = langid.classify(cell)
    else:
        lan = "NaN"
    return lan
```

```
#language detection using langid module

df['language'] = df.apply(lambda row: detect_language(row.Series), axis = 1)
```

Does anybody have suggestions on how to speed up my code or if there is another library out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [swifter](https://pypi.org/project/swifter/) to make your `df.apply()` more efficient. In addition to that, you might want to try [whatthelang](https://pypi.org/project/whatthelang/) library which should be more efficient than `langdetect`.

Comment: swifter certainly seemed to help. In the end I stick to ```langid``` because I'm having problems installing the ```whatthelang``` library for Anaconda.

Comment: I did not knew about this issue with anaconda. Another idea to speed up the process would be to predict the lang only on a subset of words instead of the whole text.

Answer (score 1):

Sample the data into multiple random sets and then use fasttext https://fasttext.cc to quickly get the results. It is fast and efficient.

```
import fasttext
path_to_pretrained_model = "lid.176.bin"
fmodel = fasttext.load_model(path_to_pretrained_model)
from datetime import datetime
df['language']=''
for i in df.index:
    ln_cnt = i
    result = fmodel.predict(str(df['prcsd_title'][i]))
    #print(result[0])
    #detector.FindLanguage(text=str(df['prcsd_title'][i]))
    df['language'][i]=result[0]
    if i%10000==0:
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        print("Current Time =", current_time)
        print(i)
```

You have to install Ubuntu if you are having Windows OS. Refer this video link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tQvghqdefTM&t=177s

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, it seems unnecessarily complicated to me to shift to Ubuntu for just a few lines of code. Using the swifter package alongside df.apply() did the trick well enough. Maybe this can be helpful to someone else

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. In my case df.apply() was not efficient enough and as per my experience the code was still running even after ~9hrs for ~127 lakh records. But fasttext took ~7hrs to complete the task.   Please let me know your sample size and hardware configuration. It will help us to understand and learn better :).     Also, installing Ubuntu is not a complicated thing, please follow this link https://www.windowscentral.com/install-windows-subsystem-linux-windows-10?amp

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from pandarallel import pandarallel
pandarallel.initialize(progress_bar=True)

"""
then instead of apply, use parallel_apply to use all the cores of your CPU to parallelize it
"""

df['new_column'] = df['your_column'].parallel_apply(lang_detect_func)
```